# Break an multidimentional array into multiple columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that I want to break into 6 div columns, and I can't seem to do it so any help with this ?

Here's the array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [title] => White
            [ref] => 24941
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [title] => Blue
            [ref] => 11395
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [title] => Red
            [ref] => 11394
        )
.
.
.
```

and here's my `foreach loop`:

```
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-xs-2">';
$i = 1;
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
    if ($i % 6 === 0) {
         echo  $value['title']. 'Ref: '. $value['ref']
    }
    echo '</div><div class="col-xs-2">';
    $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: do you want 6 columns or do you want columns having 6 rows each ?

Comment: so you never start a new row ?

Comment: I want six colums with as much as values as there in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't get what you do with `$all_colors = explode(",",$check_colors['value']);`, this should help you out:

```
$item = reset($colors);
while ($item) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if ($item)
            echo "<div class='col-xs-2'>{$item['title']}Ref: {$item['ref']}</div>";
        else
            break;
        $item = next($colors);
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Tha was just an edit i did so I forgot to remove it. :) Thanks though!